# Set host through boto configuration file

Tags: python, config, boto

I am trying to have boto read the `host` from the `.boto` file when it executes `boto.connect_s3()`. Basically, I want to have the equivalent of `boto.connect_s3(host="myhost.com")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To pass any of the `kwargs` to `connect_s3` you need to have something like this in the boto config file:

```
[s3]
host=myhost.com
check_ssl_certificate=false
```